# getting date from user in pickupdate var and want to add 3 days and store date in variable expiry date but its adding days in system current date

Tags: java, android-studio, time, days

```java
String pickupdate = pdate.getText().toString().trim();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(pickupdate));
} catch (ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
expirydate= sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Works for me. Tried with `pickupdate = "06-20-2022";` and got `expirydate` as `06-23-2022`.

Comment: What was the value of `pickupdate` at the start?  And was a stack trace printed?

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @akarnokd yes this works with a fixed string date but when I do it with input from the user through android calender it add 3 days on system current date instead of adding on entered date

Comment: As others have pointed out, you probably get a date string with invalid format, which crashes `parse`. You ignored the crash and since `Calendar` never gets updated, it will operate with the default current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.parse( 
    "06-20-2022" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" )
)
.plusDays( 3 )
```

## Details

You are using terrible date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Parse user text input.

```
String input = "06-20-2022" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

To detect faulty input, trap for `DateTimeParseException` by wrapping in a `try catch`.

Add three days.

```
LocalDate threeDaysLater = ld.plusDays( 3 ) ;
```

The *java.time* classes are bundled with Java 8+ and Android 26+. For earlier Android, the latest tooling provides most of the *java.time* functionality via [“API desugaring”](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table), or alternatively, [*ThreeTenABP*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: hey, thanks for the help my app is getting crashed on
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
with below error 

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.shahzad.feedthepoor, PID: 30977
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shahzad.feedthepoor/com.shahzad.feedthepoor.Donate_Food}: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: My API level is 32

Comment: @ShahzadAli (A) What does that error message tell you at the very end, after the last COLON character in your Comment? Read out loud to yourself. (B) An exception is *not* a crash. Be very careful with your terms when describing a programming problem. If you focus on thinking in precise terms, you’ll see the problem and the solution.

Comment: @ShahzadAli Your exception message means that you were trying to parse the empty string into a `LocalDate`. You can’t do that, and trying to throws a `DateTimeParseException`. You first need to figure out what you want your program to do in this situation. Next use a `try`-`catch` construct and catch that exception. In the `try` part add the three days and all. In the `catch` part do the error handling that you want for empty and other invalid strings.